# Angular 4 Redirecting to Root on Refresh

Tags: angular, nginx

I have an Angular 4 single page application. When I refresh the page, or enter a valid URL into the browser, I get redirected to the app's root route.

I've changed my nginx config to redirect all requests to /index.html, which fixed my initial issue of getting 404s on browser refresh.

```
server {
    listen  80;

    server_name bla.com www.bla.com

    location / {
        root  /home/admin/web/bla.com/public_html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.html;

    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    # To allow POST on static pages
    error_page  405     =200 $uri;

    location = /50x.html {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

** Edit **

Angular routing is simply handled by the RouterModule:

```
// ...

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

// ...

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'clients', component: ClientsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
    { path: 'add', component: AddClientComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
  ]},
  { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
    { path: 'add', component: AddProjectComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
  ]},
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'invoices', component: InvoicesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
    { path: 'invoices/new-invoice', component: NewInvoiceComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
  ]}
];
```

I don't really want to use HashLocationStrategy, so is there a way I can get Angular to serve the correct page when the browser refreshes or when a URL is entered?

Comment: Please share your code related to routing in angular other then doing it with nginx

Comment: I guess [AuthGuard] is causing you the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [AuthGuard] is causing you the trouble.

Comment: if your issue will resolve so you can solution this answer.